# Dokku Error when pushing: pre-receive hook declined

Tags: git, docker, digital-ocean, dokku

I am currently running into an error when running git push dokku master. The full logs can be found here: https://gist.github.com/evolfo/24f33f404308d3307120c0812018347b

I've looked at about 10 different posts with people's solutions for this problem but so far none of them have worked.

I've tried:

`sudo wget -O /etc/init/docker.conf https://raw.github.com/dotcloud/docker/master/contrib/init/upstart/docker.conf`

and

```
sudo service docker restart
```

and it didn't resolve the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!